# Dependent drop-down using ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, jsp

I have a Jsp page with a form containing two drop-down list,the first for showing the country name and the second for showing the states under the corresponding country.My Mysql database contain two tables country and state respectively.I need to populate the two drop down from the database using Ajax where the data from the database must be converted to Json object and give response as Json object.Then populate the two drop-down's based on this response Json object.Doesn't use any php or .net code here.give me the some example code to do so in Jsp using Ajax.Below is my code that i have done so far.But here the second drop-down is not getting populated.

country.jsp

```
<%@page import="java.sql.*"%>
<html>
  <head>  
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">  
  var xmlHttp;  

  function showState(str){
  if (typeof XMLHttpRequest != "undefined"){
  xmlHttp= new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
  else if (window.ActiveXObject){
  xmlHttp= new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  if (xmlHttp==null){
  alert("Browser does not support XMLHTTP Request");
  return;
  } 
  var url="state.jsp";
  url +="?count=" +str;
  xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = stateChange;
  xmlHttp.open("GET", url, true);
  xmlHttp.send(null);
  }

  function stateChange(){   
  if (xmlHttp.readyState==4 || xmlHttp.readyState=="complete"){   
  var myJson=new JSONObject(xmlHttp.responseText);
  console.log($(this).val());
  $("#state").empty();
  $("#state").append('<option value="-1">-Select State-</option>');
  $.each(myJson.arrayName, function (index, value) {
        $("#state").append('<option value="'+value.id+'">'+value.name+'</option>');
     });
        }   
  }
  </script>  
  </head>  
  <body>  
  <select name='country' onchange="showState(this.value)">  
   <option value="none">Select</option>  
<%ResultSet rs=null;
    try{
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();  
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:
3306/test","root","root");  
Statement stmt = con.createStatement();  
rs = stmt.executeQuery("Select * from country");


while(rs.next()){
 %>
  <option value="<%=rs.getString(1)%>"><%=rs.getString(2)%></option>  
  <%
}}catch(Exception e){
    }
 %>
  </select>  
  <br>  
  <div id='sta'>  
  <select id='state' name='statess' >  
  <option value='-1'>select</option>  
  </select>  
  </div>  
  </body> 
  </html>
```

state.jsp

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.*"%>
<%@page import="java.util.*,java.util.ArrayList"%>
<%@page import="net.sf.json.JSONObject"%>
<%@page import="net.sf.json.JSONArray"%>
<%
JSONArray cellarray = new JSONArray();
JSONObject cellobj = null; //new JSONObject();
JSONObject jo=new JSONObject();
String country=request.getParameter("count");  
try{
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();  
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:
3306/test","root","root");  
Statement stmt = con.createStatement();  
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("Select * from 
state where countryid='"+country+"'");  
while(rs.next()){
    cellobj = new JSONObject();
    cellobj.put("id", rs.getString(1));
    cellobj.put("name", rs.getString(3));
    cellarray.add(cellobj);
}  
jo.put("arrayName",cellarray);
response.setContentType("application/json");
response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
response.getWriter().write(jo.toString());
}
catch(Exception e){
System.out.println(e);
}
%>
```

Comment: same question in 2 hrs http://stackoverflow.com/q/20896782/1031945

Comment: The above code is working,but i need to replace the response data to json format and make the necessary changes in the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this in state.jsp page to get json array data. Remember that you need to add `json-lib-x.x.x jar` file to accomplish this.

```
<%@page import="java.sql.ResultSet"%>
<%@page import="java.util.*,java.util.ArrayList"%>
<%@page import="net.sf.json.JSONObject"%>
<%@page import="net.sf.json.JSONArray"%>
<%
JSONArray cellarray = new JSONArray();
JSONObject cellobj = null; //new JSONObject();

try{
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();  
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:
    3306/test","root","root");  
    Statement stmt = con.createStatement();  
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("Select * from state where 
    countryid='"+country+"'  ");  
    while(rs.next()){
        cellobj = new JSONObject();
        cellobj.put("id", rs.getString(1));
        cellobj.put("state", rs.getString(3));
        cellarray.add(cellobj);
    }  
    out.println(cellarray);
}
catch(Exception e){
 System.out.println(e);
}
%>
```

Also one more suggestion, try to use JSTL or EL instead of scriptlets. Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Then how to display the second dropdown using the json response?

Comment: You can check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YqLh8/) and also need to go through following [Link1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2637694/how-to-populate-a-dropdownlist-with-json-data-in-jquery), [Link2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17403795/populate-select-options-dropdown-using-json-and-jquery), [Link3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2205559/populating-dropdown-menu-with-json-data). All you need to do is google it.

Comment: Please give me the complete code for country.jsp page.Also write the code to send the response(ie,the json object) back to the country.jsp page, and how should i use this response to populate the dropdown.

Comment: We are not here to work for your tasks, we can provide you some idea and help to solve if you face any issues. If you edit your post with current code and update what you have tried so far to achieve json data, then i will continue here.

Comment: I have edited my code above.Now please tell me what the problem.

Comment: What is your response(xmlHttp.responseText) in ajax? If you get you json response correctly, you need to iterate like this `$.each(jsonData, function (index, value) {
    $("#state").append('<option value="'+value.id+'">'+value.name+'</option>');
});`

Comment: reponse is xmlHttp.responseText

Comment: I have done these changes, but still the second drop-down is getting the values from database.What's the error in my code?

Comment: I am not asking about this response, what is the response you've received in your browser console as a result of ajax? I mean if you `alert(xmlHttp.responseText);` what is the value you are getting?

Comment: {"arrayName":[{"id":"1","name":"kerala"},{"id":"2","name":"karnataka"},{"id":"4","name":"goa"}]} This is the value that i got as reponse

Comment: Your json is not valid, Please use this link for [validate](http://jsonlint.com/) your json data

Answer (score -1):

```
    $('#StateID').change(function(){
              var id=$(this).val();
              var dataString = 'id='+ id;
              $.ajax
              ({
                  type: "POST",
                  url: "city_loaddata.php",
                  data: dataString,
                  beforeSend: function() {
                  $("#uniform-CityID span").text("પસંદ કરો..");
                    },
                  cache: false,
                  success: function(html)
                  {
                      $("#CityID").html(html);
                  }
              });
        });



//city_loaddata


if($_POST['id']){
                $id = $_POST['id'];
                $SelectCity = $obj->sql_query("select * from tbl_city where StateID='".$id."'");

                echo '<option selected="selected" value="">પસંદ કરો</option>';
                for($i=0; $i<count($SelectCity); $i++)
                {
                    $CityZoneID = $SelectCity[$i]['CityID'];
                    $CityZoneName = $SelectCity[$i]['CityName'];

                    echo  '<option value="'.$CityZoneID.'">'.$CityZoneName.'</option>';

                }
        }
```